# How do I add JQuery Easing to my simple HoverIntent menu

Tags: jquery, css, hoverintent, easing, jquery-easing

- I've made a simple menu that uses [Hover Intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).
- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/39e2f/3/) is the menu (with [JQueryEasing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) linked to it).
- At the moment is just uses `.animate` to animate the opening and closing of the menu items.

**How would I add JQueryEasing to this motion (like jswing or elastic etc.)**

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/39e2f/20/